# how to get the id of all HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding HTML controls dynamically using java script. For instance, I have one button in my page. whenever I click the button, it will create on HTML control in UI page. so, I want to add click event for the controls. Is it possible to get all the UI controls ID?

Comment: Do you actually want the IDs of *all* elements on the page?

Comment: Why don't you save every UI control's ID in an array as you create them? That will make those IDs much faster to retrieve.

Comment: yes, I want add click event for all the elements like $("#element id comes her").live("click",function(){});

Comment: In that case it's better use delegate. And then check the `event.target`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probably best solution to your problem is to use [event delegate](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Suppose you have jQuery (>= 1.7) introduced, things would be simply simple, just add a custom class such as `control` to your control:

```
$(document).on(
    'click',
    '.control',
    function(e) {
        var control = e.target;
        // Work you handler
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think is a good idea obtain *IDs of all elements*, however:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[id]");
```

For a better cross browser support I suggest to you jQuery:

```
$("[id]");
```

Otherwise you have to get all elements and filter by id. Something like:

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var elements = [];

for (var i = 0, node; node = allElements[i++];)
    if (node.id) elements.push(node);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('[id]')` returns all elements that have id set.

But Beware

> this will be quite slow on a large dom